# Umbraco alternative Membership User control

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco

I been doing asp.net (vb.net, c#, javascript, jquery) programming for several years now, I've always built my sites form scratch. I was starting a new project where i require different levels of users and memberships. So I decided to use umbraco 7 downloaded loved the pre-build interfaces user and member management sites. I started working around it to figure out adding custom fields and management pages but every step has become a hassle to a point i'm losing a lot of time trying to figure out and read documentation and blogs they posted. I am 2 weeks in barely made a dent on the project. Just figuring out some js stuff took a lot of time.

I was curious instead of going through a cms system I should get a prebuilt member management asp.net site template. And alter the codes as needed. Should I consider using asp.net membership provider? Or is there any open source cms system that is easier to get into without the large learning curve of the system.

Answer (score 1):

the Member Management in Umbraco is quite decent as a starting point; if it doesn't suit your needs you can enhance it.

To start with, create a Partial View (Settings section) and you will be able to use the Login, Profile, Change Password etc. templates that are offered to you when you do so.

Then all you need to do is reference them in your views.

Comment: here is an example i am getting stuck at umbracos documentation, editorfor for registration, i want to use custom partial view. So try to get documentation for it, Thier search returns nothing about the function, This is just a simple example how poorly the documentation is prept. https://our.umbraco.org/search?q=editorfor&cat=documentation

Comment: In another example, https://our.umbraco.org/search?q=CreateRegistrationModel&cat=documentation Nothing. Its in the example registration page but not one line of documentation of their own functions.